# xread using go-redis in sentinel is failing

Tags: go, go-redis

We are using github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 to read from Redis streams.

Redis server is managed by a sentinel and the client is built as follows:

```
client := redis.NewFailoverClient(&redis.FailoverOptions{
        MasterName:    common.RedisSentinalMasterName,
        SentinelAddrs: sentinalAddr,
        PoolSize:      poolSize,
        MinIdleConns:  idleConns,
        MaxRetries:    3,
        DB:            1,
        ReadTimeout:   15 * time.Minute,
        WriteTimeout:  15 * time.Minute,
    })
```

`result, err := client.XReadStreams(ctx, streamName, id).Result()`

But it ends in an error always
"WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value"

The same code is working when connected to a standalone server